# Bash delete string with parenteses including his content

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to delete a string with parentesis an his contents, like this

(20.0 days)

```
sed -e 's/[0-9a-z]//g'
```

I can delete the numbers and the characters but I cant figure out how to get rid of the parentheses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/([^)]*)//g' file
```

will replace everything between `()` including the parantheses.

It matches `(`, followed by any character until a closing `)` then finally matches the closing `)`.

The current pattern you have will remove more than just what's inside the parantheses. For example,

```
echo "(20.0 days) some text" | sed -e 's/[0-9a-z]//g'
```

will remove the `some text` too.